# How to set values when my variable has different number of columns on each row?

Tags: google-apps-script, range, setvalue

I want to set values on a sheet, but the problem is my array has different number of columns on each row. How could I do it?

```
var results = [];

  for (var iPL in produtosLotes.descricao) {
results.push([[produtosLotes.descricao[iPL]],[produtosLotes.estoqLibLiqDisp[iPL]]]);
  };

  for (var iR=0; iR<results.length; iR++) {
    for (var iPL in produtosLotes.descricao) {
      for (var iPL2 in produtosLotes.lote[iPL]) {
        if (results[iR][0]==produtosLotes.descricao[iPL]) {
results[iR].push([produtosLotes.lote[iPL][iPL2]]);
        };
      };
    };
  };

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var estoqueLotesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ESTOQUE.LOTES');

  for (var iR=0; iR<results.length; iR++) {
var estoqueLotesRange = estoqueLotesSheet.getRange(1+iR,1,1,results[iR].length);
 estoqueLotesRange[1+iR].setValue(results[iR]); 
  };
```

Comment: Why you dont clean the number of col in your source sheet? Or maybe you can only push in your array the data of the index wanted only? And for performance, you should use setValues() (with plurial) one time, instead of looping with setValue

Comment: You can try to do it by row